# Installing a .inf file using a windows batch file

Tags: windows

When you right click on a .inf file you have an option to "Install". I want to install a .inf file from the command line using a batch file. What is the "right" way to do this?

Thanks!

[edit]
I should clarify that I am trying to run this on Windows XP (and not Vista). Though I appriciate (and up-voted) the below answer mentioning InfDefaultInstall.exe, I believe that program was not shipped with XP.

Comment: I've added a note on XP. But still, the location where Windows looks for the command to execute didn't change since then :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find the command when looking at the `HKCR\inffile\shell\Install\command` registry key. On Windows XP this is

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe setupapi,InstallHinfSection DefaultInstall 132 %1
```

on Windows Vista and later this would be

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\InfDefaultInstall.exe "%1"
```

To use the batch file across several Windows versions you would need some trickery. You could use `reg.exe` to query for the key and try parsing the output (I didn't find a quick way of getting only the value from `reg`). If you know what platforms you're running on you could also hard-code the command lines and switch according to the Windows version (which would need another hack to find that out. `%OS%` doesn't tell you more than "Windows NT", unfortunately.).

Comment: Does this still apply for windows 7?

Comment: `Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\inffile\shell\Install\command` indicates yes.

Answer (score 2):

```
rem tested/works

:inf
ver | findstr /il "Version 6." > nul 
if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 goto :vista

:xp
start/wait rundll32.exe setupapi,InstallHinfSection DefaultInstall 4 %_%
goto :eof
:vista
%SystemRoot%\System32\InfDefaultInstall.exe "%_%"

:eof
```

Answer (score 2):

Should works on any Windows system that has IE 4.0+:

```
RunDll32 advpack.dll,LaunchINFSection <file.inf>,DefaultInstall
```