# Installing a driver (.inf) file from command line

Tags: command-line, driver, inf

I am working in Windows 8.1.
I need to install a driver file (`.inf` file) from command line. Which command do I need to use?

I know I have many other method for installing a `.inf` file, but I must install this from command line.

Please help me
Thanks in advance...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619604/installing-a-inf-file-using-a-windows-batch-file

Answer (score 21):

Granger's comment works in Windows 7 too. According to MS, *PnPUtil (PnPUtil.exe) is included in every version of Windows, starting with Windows Vista*.

It is useful for **device drivers** that do not have default install (right-click "Install" does not work for them).

`pnputil -i -a <driverinf>`

Comment: how install unsigned driver win10 ,?

Answer (score 18):

**The default way for device drivers is:**

```
pnputil -i -a <driverinf>
```

**Legacy Drivers can´t be installed with pnputil and have to use LaunchINFSectionEx-Call**

I tested the following and it works with several drivers from Windows 2000 up to Windows 10, 2012R2, 2016, 2019.

```
rundll32.exe advpack.dll,LaunchINFSectionEx ykmd.inf,Yubico64_Install.NT,,4,N
```

*Pay attention to use the correct section*

*The correct section of the inf-File must be used, when there is no [DefaultInstall]-Section*. This lacks in most answers. Look it up in your drivers inf-File and **use the correct section** (in my example "Yubico64_Install.NT"). Using the wrong section wont prompt an error. Im my example I use Quiet mode, no UI (4) and Never reboot (N) to install the driver automated via GPO. All options are documented in detail here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa768006(v%3Dvs.85)

Answer (score 2):

There are many variants ... and many complications with newer versions of Windows.

But for starters, try something like this:

`rundll32.exe advpack.dll,LaunchINFSectionEx myinf.inf,,c:\temp\mydata.cab,36`

- http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/104891-how-can-i-install-a-inf-file-from-the-command-line/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- [Programmatic driver install via .inf causing reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359696/programatic-driver-install-via-inf-causing-reboot)

Note: beware older links that suggest "setupapi" instead of "advpack".  You definitely want advpack.dll.

Comment: What about 64-bit Windows? Is it rundll64.exe?

Comment: There's no such thing as "rundll64.exe".  Q: Did you try "rundll32"?  What happened?

Comment: Not yet, but I know that lower-level APIs for driver installation require the main exe to be 32 or 64-bit depending on the host system. I'm trying to install a driver programmatically: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541255(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Speaking of newer versions of Windows. In [Hyper-V Server 2012 r1 & r2](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/jj647787(v=ws.11).aspx), the command-line is: `pnputil -i -a <driverinf>`