# Installing .inf file in Windows 10/migrating away from snetcfg.exe

Tags: windows, driver, virtualbox, inf

I am the maintainer of Portable-VirtualBox. A wrapper for VirtualBox to make it easy to take virtual machines with you on a USB stick. To do so we have to load some drivers from VirtualBox when a user starts the portable version on a new machine.

Currently we have been using snetcfg.exe to load .inf files. Unfortunately snetcfg.exe dos not work on Windows 10, but I have not been able to figure out how to install this driver in an different way.

This is the code used today:

```
      If @OSArch = "x86" Then
        RunWait (@ScriptDir&"\data\tools\snetcfg_x86.exe -v -u sun_VBoxNetFlt", @ScriptDir, @SW_HIDE)
        RunWait (@ScriptDir&"\data\tools\snetcfg_x86.exe -v -l .\"& $arch &"\drivers\network\netflt\VBoxNetFlt.inf -m .\"& $arch &"\drivers\network\netflt\VBoxNetFltM.inf -c s -i sun_VBoxNetFlt", @ScriptDir, @SW_HIDE)
      EndIf
      If @OSArch = "x64" Then
        RunWait (@ScriptDir&"\data\tools\snetcfg_x64.exe -v -u sun_VBoxNetFlt", @ScriptDir, @SW_HIDE)
        RunWait (@ScriptDir&"\data\tools\snetcfg_x64.exe -v -l .\"& $arch &"\drivers\network\netflt\VBoxNetFlt.inf -m .\"& $arch &"\drivers\network\netflt\VBoxNetFltM.inf -c s -i sun_VBoxNetFlt", @ScriptDir, @SW_HIDE)
      EndIf
      FileCopy (@ScriptDir&"\"& $arch &"\drivers\network\netflt\VBoxNetFltNobj.dll", @SystemDir, 9)
      FileCopy (@ScriptDir&"\"& $arch &"\drivers\network\netflt\VBoxNetFlt.sys", @SystemDir&"\drivers", 9)
      RunWait (@SystemDir&"\regsvr32.exe /S "& @SystemDir &"\VBoxNetFltNobj.dll", @ScriptDir, @SW_HIDE)
```

The .inf files used are here: http://runarb.com/div/netflt/

Any advise on how to install this driver automatically in Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `sc` command as described [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754599(WS.10).aspx).
It will work fine on all new Windows Platforms.
For the inf, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496847/installing-a-driver-inf-file-from-command-line) (and/or [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557251(v=vs.85).aspx)) could be relevant.

Comment: Any suggestion on with what parameters to run the sc command?

I have tried running this:


`sc create VBoxNetFlt binpath="C:\temp\Portable-VirtualBox\app64\drivers\network\netflt\VBoxNetFlt.sys" type=kernel start=auto error=normal displayname=PortableVBoxNetFlt`


It give me a successful response, but it appear that that is not correct, because bridged networking still fails with the same error.


I have also tried to inspect the driver status with Nirsoft InstalledDriversList , and her the driver shows up, but is listed as not loaded.


Maybe I have to do something in addition to running sc?

Comment: `sc start VBoxNetFlt`?

Comment: sc start VBoxNetFlt fails like this:  `[SC] StartService FAILED 1058:

The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.`